# Pidgin facebook IM protocol line

Tags: pidgin

I spent my last 3hours trying to remove this annoying line from Pidgin facebook IMs.
Does anyone know how can I make it disspear?
I just want messaging to look clear and compact

Here is the image of what I am talking about:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2qnwcp1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an alias for yourself. Setting one in facebook directly might work.

If not check the `Accounts->[your facebook account]` menu for a `Set nickname` menu item or `Set User Info` menu item.

If those don't exist or changing them doesn't help your problem then a local account alias definitely will. Select the `Accounts->[your facebook account->Edit Account` menu item and then fill in the `Local alias` field.

None of these will remove that line but they will control what you *see* for yourself on that line.